# How to sum up all rows total count?

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

I'm using the following query, I need to show Grand Total count but it is throwing error like

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

```
SELECT  
      ISNULL(OQ.GroupID,'') GroupName,
      CONVERT(VARCHAR, ISNULL(COUNT(CASE WHEN RequestStatusKey IN ( 1, 2 ) THEN OrderRecordID END), 0)) TotalRecord,
      SUM(COUNT(CASE WHEN RequestStatusKey IN ( 1, 2 ) THEN OrderRecordID END)) AS GrandTotal
FROM dbo.tblDesk OQ                     
WHERE OQ.RequestStatusKey IN ( 1, 2 ) 
      AND OQ.OrderTypeKey <> 1 
      AND OQ.GroupID IS NOT NULL                                        
GROUP BY OQ.GroupID
ORDER BY OQ.GroupID
```

[image]

I just need to Grand total.

Comment: I'm unclear what you're looking for. Do you want a grand total like what you'd get using `WITH ROLLUP` or do you want a separate column that counts the totals altogether (which you could achieve with something like an `SUM(COUNT(...)) OVER()`)?

Comment: I did using With Roll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message suggests, you can not use aggregate function inside another aggregate function.

For your query to achieve SUM of `OrderRecordId` when `RequestStatusKey IN (1,2)` you can use `SUM` without using `COUNT` like this:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN RequestStatusKey IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS GrandTotal
```

However, as Tim suggested, since you have already used `RequestStatusKey IN (1,2)` in your `WHERE` clause you don't need to use conditional `SUM`. Just use `COUNT` without condition:

```
COUNT(OrderRecordId) AS GrandTotal
```

**UPDATE:**

Since you want to show sum of the all rows count in the same result, you can use [`ROLLUP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#group-by-rollup) for that:

```
SELECT  
      ISNULL(OQ.GroupID,'Grand Total') GroupName,
      CONVERT(VARCHAR, COUNT(OrderRecordID)) TotalRecord
FROM tblDesk OQ                     
WHERE OQ.RequestStatusKey IN ( 1, 2 ) 
      AND OQ.GroupID IS NOT NULL                                        
GROUP BY ROLLUP (OQ.GroupID)
ORDER BY OQ.GroupID
```

See this [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/becde/2).

Comment: The OP's current `WHERE` clause already restricts `RequestStatusKey` to only values of `(1, 2)`.  Then what is the point of the conditional sum?

Comment: Ah, didn't see the condition in `WHERE` clause. Updated.

Comment: Upvoted; either just the sum, or maybe that `WHERE` clause should be removed entirely.

Comment: In this case `COUNT` should be used since `SUM` will sum up `OrderRecordId`

Comment: No my requirement is i need to show sum of all rows total in last row

Comment: @PK-1825 Then you can use [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to get count and then use `SUM` from that temp table.

Comment: @PK-1825: Got it. Updated the answer.

Comment: I have used like 'GROUP BY OQ.GroupID WITH ROLLUP' bcz GROUP BY ROLLUP (OQ.GroupID) thrown error.

Comment: And one more thing How to show total in last row? now it is showing in first row.

Comment: `ORDER BY IIF(OQ.GroupID IS NULL,1,0), OQ.GroupID`. This will put null at last then order by GroupID.